# Article usage in scientific context

Tags: articles

While editing a manuscript, I came across the following sentence.

> However, Li–S batteries also show several serious defects, including poor conductivity, the large volume expansion (about 80%) of sulfur as cathode, and the shuttle effect of intermediate products (lithium polysulfides) during charge/discharge processes.

In the above sentence, do we need to add an article before "cathode", as it is a countable singular noun, or shall we leave it as such, because the emphasis is on "large volume expansion"?

Comment: I believe it should be *at the cathode* or *in the cathode*.

Comment: Thanks SLC for your suggestion, I checked the possibility of your suggestion in the manuscript, but in this article, actually sulfur has been used as a cathode.

Comment: In that case I would suggest *large volume expansion of the sulfur cathode*.

Comment: @SLC, this seems a better edit, I guess

Comment: I recommend, "However, Li–S batteries also show several serious defects, including poor conductivity, the large volume expansion (about 80%) of sulfur **used as a** cathode, and the shuttle effect of intermediate products (lithium polysulfides) during charge/discharge processes."

Comment: Sulfur cathode sounds correct (if you are writing for an american audience, otherwise sulphur), but science question... sulphur is not a conductor, so how does it function as a cathode?

Comment: ["and large volume expansion of the sulfur (~80%) cathode"](http://www.greencarcongress.com/2016/05/20160516-li-s.html) so just remove `as` and add `the` before sulfur

Comment: Get rid of the *the* before *large volume expansion*.

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the article sometimes before nouns that are describing generic roles that can apply to any situation.  Articles try to answer the question "which" for a noun X, but in cases where nouns are used abstractly, this question doesn't need to be answered (because there is no X).

> John as manager took great pride in his employee's work.

So here, we mean John as a manager in general.  "Which manager" is not answered because it's not important to the speaker/writer.  The speaker/writer is trying to convey you could stick John in any management role and he would take pride in his employee's work.  Contrast with the below:

> John as the manager took great pride in his employee's work.

which means John as a manager - which manager? - likely the one of his current workplace with his current employees.  Here the question of "which manager" is answered (don't forget *the* relies on previous sentences/context to work).

So in your original sentence, sulfur is acting as a cathode, but not a cathode in a specific reaction or whatever.

Comment: The above explanation has really given me a deep insight into the context. Thank you.

Comment: Difference between **as a manager** and **as the manager** please.